# Is there a Python method for creating a custom convolution?

Tags: python, numpy, cellular-automata

I'm trying to create an efficient implementation of a totalistic cellular automaton with three possible colors for each cell as in this image from Stephen Wolfram's book, *A New Kind of Science*:

[image: totalistic cellular automaton]

If I have a `numpy` array, can I create a new `numpy` array by having a window of width 3 that slides over the original array, adds the three elements, and uses this sum as an index into a look-up table for the rule?

I was thinking I could use `np.correlate`, but that wouldn't do the look-up in the rule array.  Perhaps I could do that afterwards with a map.

Answer (score 0):

```
    a = self.array
    i = self.next
    window = [1, 1, 1]
    row = self.array[i - 1]
    correlated_row = np.correlate(row, window, mode="same")
    next_row = np.array([self.table[7 - total - 1] for total in correlated_row])
    a[i] = next_row
    self.next += 1
```